# Rails 5, has_ancestory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am using the gem [Ancestory](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to produce a dynamic menu structure.

I have a Menu model that can have several levels of nesting.

I'm using rails 5 API and I want to return json that contains each root menu and its subsequent children.

I have tried so many different ways I dont know which to post but I want to end up with something like this

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Menu 1",
    "ancestry": null,
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Menu 2",
        "ancestry": null
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Menu 3",
        "ancestry": null,
        "children": {
          "4": {
            "id": 42,
            "label": "Menu 4",
            "ancestry": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "Menu 5",
    "ancestry": null
  }
}
```

So i have each menu and its children and thier children etc. Is there an easy way to do this using ancestory? It seems all the methods can only be called on a singular item, I can't just get everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `Menu.arrange_serializable`.

That will return something similar to what you are looking for.  You can massage it further by using its block form.  You can read more in the docs.

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#arrangement

Comment: Its so clear now that you point it out! Thank you so much, you have saved my day!

Comment: Anytime - happy to help!